# how do I reverse the order of a list with a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is what I did and my output.
Why is it wrong?

```
routers = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4']

for router in routers:
    print('Router in use is', (router[::-1]))
```

Output:

```
Router in use is 1R
Router in use is 2R
Router in use is 3R
Router in use is 4R
```

expecting:

```
Router in use is R4
Router in use is R3
Router in use is R2
Router in use is R1
```

Comment: You reversed the order of the wrong thing. Think again *of what* you want to reverse the order.

Comment: `for router in reversed(routers): print('Router in use is', router)`

Comment: If you still don't see what @mkrieger1 is talking about, try adding `print(router)` and `print(router[::-1])` to your code.

Comment: For whatever reason you would want to use for loop, I suggest you use `range` rather. Like `for i in range(len(routers)):`
 `print('Router in use is ', (routers[len(routers)-(i+1)]))`

Answer (score 0):

```py
routers = ['R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R4']

for router in routers[::-1]:
    print('Router in use is', router)
```

close but seems you were a little mixed up